# Mac OS and distributed compile

Tags: macos, xcode

Is there an alternative to distcc on Mac OS X Lion?

Apple recently removed distcc from Xcode. It's a feature I use a lot. If I want to update to the latest version of Xcode I will have to give it up.

Do you know of any alternative software that would allow me to distribute compilation over LAN (preferably directly from Xcode)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question has been asked on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9328824/189804) also - it seem that it has simply been removed with no word from Apple, no response in the developer forums (surprise!) and no word about what might replace it.

I can't find any discussion in the LLVM project about a future distributed approach either.

Can you share any information about what you are compiling? I'm curious because I generally only do small apps.

Comment: I found the question you linked to and turned to this site to see if there would be another solution that works on OS X.

Comment: I'm working on a multi platform video game. Usually compilation is fast as only the recently changed files and files including them are recompiled, but currently I have to adjust/add a few macros for multi platform support which are used across the entire project (3rd party libs included). It makes each compile a hell.

Comment: I was looking for something like XGE for Mac OS X. If Apple forces us do build apps with LLVM, I think the solution will be to configure and maintain distcc manually, and use make files to build each game during dev. Then before release simply build them using LLVM. I will see what I do when we get to the point where Xcode 4.2 fails us.

Comment: Actually, it was documented as deprecated in 4.2 and slated to be removed in 4.3 in the release notes: https://devimages.apple.com.edgekey.net/downloads/xcode/xcode_42_for_lion_readme.pdf (I overlooked it then, also.)

Answer (score 2):

You might be out of luck on this one. If your not trying to run the latest iOS SDK with Xcode 4, you may want to try installing a XCode 3 (i think it goes up to iOS 4.2) or XCode 4 separately with a different path and using it's distributed build capability -- although I think doing this might be more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: I currently have the 4.2 and the latest version installed, it's very simple to keep them together since v4.3 installs as an app in the Applications directory, it leaves the 4.2 install intact in the Developer directory. But I worry about future updates, as I will probably lose the ability to use 4.2 in Mountain Lion. It will be a problem next time I buy new Macs.

Comment: This thread is old. The commandline tools should give you what you want in the latest release.